# Spawn process in Java, similar as double-click

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder, winsxs, sxs

I have a Java application and i would like to spawn a new process(start a .bat file), that will essintially do the same thing as by double-clicking on it.

I have tried both `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and `ProcessBuilder` in order to spawn that process. Both those approaches work (they can start the .bat file), ***but my problem is that*** they do not actually do the exact same thing as by double clicking on it.

More specifically, this .bat file starts up a JVM (java.exe MyMainClass) which is configured to run using Windows SxS (side by side). Thus, i have created appropriate **java.exe.config** and  **java.exe.manifest** files. When i doulbe click on that, the java application starts and the appropriate .dlls are loaded succesfuly (reason i need SxS).

My problem is that when i start the exact same .bat file (with the exact same arguments and process environment), either by using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, it doesn't seem to take into consideration my SxS configuration, thus the .dlls that i need are not loaded at all, resulting in errors.

Does anyone have any clue how to launch this .bat file the same way as windows laucnhes it when i am double clicking on it? 
Additionally, does anyone have any experience with Java SxS deployment? I cannot really understand why ProcessBuilder ignores my SxS configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting a cmd window, which loads your application bat file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"C:\\path\\to\\the\\app.bat arg1 arg2\"");
```